# Cannot put a Set<String> in sharedPreferences.putStringSet()?

Tags: java, android

Good morning! I am trying to make a toDo list and I want to do this through the sharedPreferences. The problem is that once I get the contents of the location and then add it to the contents of the list and try to push it back to sharedPreferences, I get a strange error. It does not make sense to me because the taskSet Set is defined by the items in the sharedPreferences, so how could it be the incorrect type?

```
    public void putInSharedPreferences(View view){
    Intent i = getIntent();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> taskSet = sp.getStringSet("taskSet", new HashSet<String>());


    String task = i.getStringExtra("taskText");
    taskSet.add(task);
    sp.edit().putStringSet(taskSet).apply();

    int minutes = i.getIntExtra("chosenMinutes", 0);


}
```

The error I receive:

> putStringSet (java.lang.String, Set) in Editor cannot be applied to (java.util.Set)

Comment: The error says that the method expects **two** parameters, of type `String` and `Set`, and you're only providing one parameter, of type `Set`. Which part of that do you not understand?

Comment: Lol I guess I didn't understand the error. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`putSetString()` takes *two* parameters:  A key, which is a`String`, along with a `Set<String>`.  So you'd put the set like this:

```
    sp.edit().putStringSet("taskSet", taskSet).apply();
```

See the method definition [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) for more info.